# gtk# Vbox not showing up

Tags: gtk#

I'm trying to get 2 VBoxes up in my gtk# application. The problem is, they are not showing up at all. I cannot see the button. What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using Kassa;

public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window
{
    VBox left, right;
    public MainWindow() : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build();
        this.Title = "Kassa";
        this.SetSizeRequest(1920, 1080);
        //this.Fullscreen();

        left = new VBox();

        left.HeightRequest = this.HeightRequest;

        right = new VBox(true, 0);

        right.HeightRequest = this.HeightRequest;
        right.WidthRequest = 64 * 4;

        Button button = new Button("b");
        right.Add(button);
        right.PackStart(button, true, false, 0);

        button.Show();

        this.Add(left);
        this.Add(right);

        right.Show();

        this.ShowAll();
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }
}
```

I have tried every possible combination of Add and ShowAll I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Window.Add()` just once, to add the containing widget (a **VBox** or similar), and then employ the `Box.PackStart()` and `Box.PackEnd()` methods within that container in order to create complex layouts.

```
    Build();
    this.Title = "Kassa";

    VBox container = new VBox();
    left = new VBox();
    right = new VBox(true, 0);

    Button button = new Button( "b" );
    right.Add(button);
    right.PackStart( button, true, false, 0 );

    container.PackStart( left, true, true, 5 );
    container.PackStart( right, true, true, 5 );

    this.Add( container );
    this.ShowAll();
```

If you had added the boxes in reverse order, you would see a giant button occupying the whole screen. The explanation is that `Window.Add()` just adds one item, if you call it twice, then the former is forgotten, and the latter used... exactly the one that had nothing (the former had a button), creating the illusion that nothing was being shown.

Hope this helps.